# New value is only available in sendAsynchronousRequest - Swift

Tags: swift, sendasynchronousrequest

```
var arrayData: [String] = []

let bodyData = "parameter=test"

let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "Link to php file")
let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
{
    (response, data, error) in
        var output = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        self.arrayData = self.JSONParseArray(output)

        println(self.arrayData) //Print the result
}

println(self.arrayData) //Print nothing
```

It look like the new value is only available in sendAsynchronousRequest

Is there a way to make the new value accessible out of the sendAsynchronousRequest ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting data out of the NSURLResponse completion block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352901/getting-data-out-of-the-nsurlresponse-completion-block) - (Didn't you ask (and delete) a very similar question yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513767/variable-in-closure-is-only-available-in-the-closure-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sendAsynchronousRequest` is, as the name suggests, asynchronous. So your final `println` runs before the request is complete. After the completion handler runs, the new data will be available for all readers (in or outside this handler).

Comment: Ok and how can i fix this?

Comment: What do you want to do? In the code above, you've already fixed it. You `println()` inside the completion handler, which is run at the correct time. What else are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wan't the last println to have the value cause i need this value for my tableView function

Comment: That would be a synchronous request (which is available on `NSURLConnection`, but then you will block your entire UI while you wait for the connection. You cannot have a table view wait for a network connection. In the completion handler, tell your cell to tableview to update itself.

Answer (score 1):

`sendAsynchronousRequest` requires a callback passed as argument, which is executed once the asynchronous request has been completed. That's out of the linear flow in your code.

This is what happens:

1. you call `sendAsynchronousRequest`
2. the request is started, but the function returns immediately (it doesn't wait for the request to be completed)
3. the `println` line is executed next (last line in your code)
4. some time later, the asynchronous request is completed, and the closure is executed
5. the closure assigns a value to `self.arrayData`

If you want to use the updated value, you have to change the logic a little bit. You can call another closure or a class method (meaning an instance method, not a static one) to post process that variable once it has been set.

Comment: Ok and how can i fix this?

Comment: You cannot do that in a linear way. As mentioned in my answer, you have to do something from within the closure - usually call an instance method of the class to process the received value